# bind(this) confusion in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, bind

Im reading on Reactjs and

```
 componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

from my understand bind this if for `this.setState` so that when called outside, `this` will be referring to the proper object. But how come we dont need it for `this.props.source`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this.props.source` is a param passed to `$.get` - it still has the correct context as it's executing inside the `componentDidMount` method. It's only in the `$.get` method's callback that the context would otherwise be lost, which is being executed from somewhere in the jQuery lib.

Another way to preserve the context is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (this is es6 so you'd need a transpiler for now), which will do the binding for you:

```
$.get(this.props.source, (result) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Np, yep that's another solution

Comment: If you dont mind let me ask one more question: I was looking at this: `https://jsfiddle.net/n47gckhr/1038/`, and `FilterableProductTable` has a callback function `handleUserInput`, which contain a this.setState. It passes it to his child, and his child can use it to change the state of the parent (FilterableProductTable). How come we dont have to bind this to the parent, wouldnt the `this` in this.setState refer to child when child use this callback? Thanks

Comment: That's because when you use react.createClass and you're binding to a Dom event that react supports, it's doing the binding to "this" for you. Note you don't get that when using es6 class with react

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me!!! Now I see why learning framework before mastering vanilla js can be a bad thing, so many hidden 'magic'